# store each word from a text file into a list

Tags: python, string, list

So I'm trying to make a program that reads a file, and stores each word into a list of strings.  I can add each line into a list of strings, (see the code below) but how do I add each individual word into a list of strings?

Also, since this is a Mad Libs program, I'll have some phrases that will look like, *noun*, or *body part*.  How would I store body part into the list as one string, since it is technically two separate words?

Code for reference:

```
def main():
  file_list = []
  while True: #while loop that runs until the user puts in a file name...
    #or types in quit
    #asks the user for a file name, or gives them an option to quit
    file_name = raw_input("Enter in the name of the file, or type in quit to quit: ")
    if file_name == "quit":
            sys.exit(0) #quits the program
    else:
            try: #attempts to open the file
                fin = open(file_name)
                break
            except: #prints out if file name doesn't exist
                    print "No, no, file no here."
  for eachLine in fin: #strips out the new lines from the file
        file_list.append(eachLine.strip())
  print file_list
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: what's the problem with your code so far?

Comment: It adds in each line from the text file into a list, but I need it to add each individual word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
file_list.extend(eachLine.split())
```

Comment: That seems to split up the words into separate letters.

I might be putting it in wrong, but I need take a list of string lines, and split them up into separate words.

Comment: @user1768884, I'm not sure what you've done wrong, but that won't split each letter unless there is space around every letter. Add the new version of the code to your question

Comment: Got it to work. No idea what I was doing wrong in the first place. Thank you! =)